# Select in 2 databases with Kohana PHP

Tags: php, database, kohana, kohana-3.3, mysql-error-1146

How to JOIN tables in different databases in Kohana?

```
$tb_new = 'db_zaboo_feed.feed_' . $feed;
            $ids = DB::query(Database::SELECT, 
                             "SELECT d.fuid_id, d.user_id FROM db_zaboo.displays d
                             LEFT JOIN $tb_new f ON(d.fuid_id = f.uid)
                             WHERE d.user_id = (SELECT user_id FROM $tb_new GROUP BY user_id) AND f.uid IS NULL")->execute();
```

ERROR:

```
Database_Exception [ 1146 ]: Table 'db_zaboo.displays' doesn't exist [ SELECT d.fuid_id, d.user_id FROM db_zaboo.displays d LEFT JOIN db_zaboo_feed.feed_3 f ON(d.fuid_id = f.uid) WHERE d.user_id = (SELECT user_id FROM db_zaboo_feed.feed_3 GROUP BY user_id) AND f.uid IS NULL ]
```

Comment: Not a Kohana user, but this shouldn't be possible. the query is called whilst connected to a specific db. You'd need to have two connections running and then perform the two separate queries and logic yourself

Comment: From to specify the database so: "->execute($this->_db_group);"
but do not know how to two databases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a Kohana specific question. It is a MySQL question.

For operating on multiple databases in the same query, you have to use table names with its database name. Such as:

```
SELECT * FROM database1.table1 WHERE database1.table1.id IN (SELECT table1_id FROM database2.table2)
```

Be careful: by literally writing your query, I am not sure if Kohana's query builder prevents SQL injection attacks as it would do by building the SQL query using the query builder's specific functions. I would prevent it using the function [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Answer (score 0):

To use a different database config group pass either the name or the config object to execute().

$result = $query->execute('config_name')

http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/database/query/builder#executing
http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/database/config#connection-settings

Comment: From to specify the database so: "->execute($this->_db_group);" but do not know how to two databases